# Trouble installing SCons

Tags: macos, terminal

I am following the first set of instructions for Mac OS X on this website: [Installing V8 on Mac OS X](http://www.nakedjavascript.com/installing-v8-on-mac-os-x-and-linux). But, when I try running `sudo port install scons subversion` I get the following error:

> Warning: No index(es) found! Have you synced your source indexes?
>   Error: Port scons not found
>   Before reporting a bug, first run the command again with the -d flag to get complete output.

Any advice on how to help me with this would be greatly appreciated. I am very inept with Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org). In that case, you must first update the ports directory by issuing the command

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

After that, you should be able to install the scons and subversion ports. Check out the [Using MacPorts](http://guide.macports.org/#using) guide for more help.

Comment: Awww works like a charm. And thanks for the reference too!